# Is possible to get the instance variable names of a NSManagedObject with the Obj-C Runtime?

Tags: ios, core-data, objective-c-runtime

I am doing an automatic mapping from XML to NSObject while parsing if the XML nodes names match the NSObject instance variable names. It's done through obj-c runtime easily with (elementName is a XML child node name):

```
    void* ivarValue = nil;
    Ivar ivar = object_getInstanceVariable(self, [elementName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &ivarValue);   // Get the iVar with name 'elementName' from current instance
```

I tried to do the same with NSManagedObject with no success. Is possible to use objc/runtime.h with Core Data? If not, is there an alternative to retrieve the instance variables or its type (assuming you know its names)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the NSManagedObject [entity description](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html) for the relevant properties and use KVC for setting values